# How to add OnClickListener for items from ItemizedOverlay

Tags: java, android

I have following class extended ItemizedOverlay. This class draws many icons on Google Map (MapView). I need to make a listener for clicking by any item of ItemizedOverlay, but I don't know how I can do it. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you should overide `onTap()` method of your `ItemizedOverlay` class.

```
 @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final OverlayItem items = mapOverlay.get(index); //items is your ArrayList<OverlayItem> for populating of ItemizedOverlay

        //insert your code for action there
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();

        return true;
    }
```

I hope this helps.